# python tkinter image missing

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to have a image of a map next to my application I am creating right now, which includes a filter system. However I wasn't sure why it wasn't showing up. Here are snippits from my code

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

    class MainPage(tk.Frame):

        def __init__(self,app):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self)

            frame_A = Frame(self,width=930,height=780) 
            frame_A.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2,rowspan=3)        
            contentmap = Frame(frame_A)
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/Users/J/Desktop/unknown.png"))
            panel = Label(contentmap, image = img) 

    App().mainloop()
```

Additionally I would like to ask for some advice as to whether it was possible to make my image a interactive image like if I were to zoom in google maps.

Thanks a million!

Comment: Have you searched this site for an answer? This question has been asked and answered dozens of times. Perhaps if you tell us what you searched for we can tweak the existing answers so they are easier to find.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have been looking at websites like http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

Furthermore, I have tried making this a separate test code just to see if it brings up a image in root, however for some reason it doesn't show up in my current code, which is very strange.

Comment: You can help by showing us the search terms you used on this site.

Comment: @JasperYip: Note the paragraph *"You must keep a reference ..."* form [effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: Your comment has nothing to do with this question. The comment area isn't designed for extended discussions.